# Which way to go when setting up a database for my server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, server, socket.io

I'm developing a websocket real time browser game ( socketio nodejs) and wanted to start implementing my database and would like to know which type of database (nosql, sql .. ) would fit my situation best.

A small description of how i intend to use it :

- I want to have game rooms with all their options stored ( which can be changed frequently)
- a list of the connected users and their linked accounts( if a user is a guest he won't have a linked account, however if he does it would be linked with another table containing some extra data like lvl or something like that)
- a list of user thema they like ( so for example when a game starts, it will take the themas in common for all users to use the game) all typical themas are stored in another big table that has a lot of data that won't be updated in a while.

So basically I have some tables that need a lot of quick and concurrent access which get updated and deleted frequently and some that don't need it and have a lot of permanent data.

I was thinking about using mongodb but honestly don't want to commit on something i don't have experience with ( i do have sql knowledge). I need suggestions thanks

Comment: I would go with SQL...as i do for any project :D Note that if you plan on performing a lot of create/update/delete operations, you will need to setup your  table indexes properly(not to have TOO MANY indexes), in order to maintain good performance. Each insertion also updates the index. If this application is planned to be used by many people, i would suggest making a small research on how to setup indexes "correctly".

Comment: Thanks i'll look that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TD;LR**: I would personally go with PostgreSQL.

Recently, I had the same question as you, but with the only difference, I was not looking to build game rooms. After some research, I was convinced that PostgreSQL is awesome and suitable for every project. Well, tech giants use it too, including Facebook, Uber, Netflix... (https://stackshare.io/postgresql). It is scalable, easy to set one DB up, great community with lots of tutorials (both videos and articles) and it is also extensible, as it supports JSON, which is great!

You can use a great ORM for Node.js, such as TypeORM or Sequelize. Furthermore, I suggest you take a look at GraphQL, an API that has subscriptions (real-time operations). As I guess it will be a web application, I highly recommend you to go with React.js for the front-end functionalities, which interact great with GraphQL & Node.js. Last but not least, lots of developers and companies use both MongoDB and PostgreSQL for different functionalities and purposes for each. For user's tables use PostgreSQL, for multiple "big" JSON objects use MongoDB.

I hope that helps and lets you understand what you want in a more clear way. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I had PostgreSQL in my sight at it seemed to fit well what I needed and was a bit doubtful if i should commit on it as going back would eat a lot of my time. I'll start reading up on it.

Comment: My pleasure! If you are a beginner with PostgreSQL, I suggest you watching freeCodeCamp's tutorial on it. I found it nice and the teacher was friendly (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw--VYLpxG4&t=12799s).